# SQL Server stored procedure which returns resultset not present in IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the requirement.. I have a list of dates for which data needs to be available in the table. For example

```
Date1 09/01/2014
Date2 09/02/2014
Date3 09/03/2014
Date4 09/04/2014
Date5 09/05/2014
```

However sometimes data doesn't get updated for one of the dates for

Example - Date5 09/05/2014.

I need to return the dates for which there are no rows present in the table.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any flag which you set after Updating the row?If yes then try simple query in which flag value is false you fetch those rows Suppose you have Columns col1,col2,date_col,flag_col(bit) , You query will be like <CODE>"Select * from your_table where flag_col <> 1"</CODE>

Comment: Not Really,I dont have to update the table with any flag.Here is the scenario in case there are 5 dates passed in the Input to the Stored procedure and the query looks like select * from table where dates in ( list of dates) then it would return resultset of all the dates available in the table.Just in case one of the dates is not available it wont show up.I want those dates for which there is no resultset.

Comment: It would be useful if you showed table structures and update statements which are causing you problems, you are likely to get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all your input dates in to a temp table, say #t. Then do something in line of,

```
SELECT date FROM #t
WHERE #t.date NOT IN (SELECT date FROM yourtable WHERE yourtable.date IN (list-of-input-dates))
```

Or you may try the equivalent left outer join syntax,

```
SELECT #t.date FROM #t LEFT OUTER JOIN yourtable
               ON #t.date = yourtable.date
               WHERE yourtable.date IS NULL
```